# How to fetch related objects

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

For a graph like this:

Company -> (many) Customer -> (many) Invoices
Company <-> ASX Record

I have a traditional hierarchy of Companies with customers that receive invoices.

Then I have a table that has today's ASX ranking/market cap etc. The ASX record is assigned the ID of the Company and the Company is assigned the ID of the ASX record.

I thought that when I built resolvers that return all records, I could get details from various objects by running a query like:

```
query {
  asx {
    CompanyName
    Code
    company {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

but `asx.company` comes back as null. That makes sense as company has not been loaded. But I thought Apollo would do some magic based on my typedefs and assemble the reponse as the expected graph of objects and attributes/values:

```
type asx {
   id : ID!
   Rank : Int
   Code : String
   CompanyName : String
   Price : String
   LastDay : String
   PastWeek : String
   PastMonth : String
   PastYear : String
   Sector : String
   MktCap : String
   company : company
}

type company {
   id : ID!
   asx : asx
   name : String
   code : String
   address : String
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this? My usecase for this idea is purely to enable prototyping with in-memory database, so there are just arrays of objects behind the resolvers.

Do I have to resolve the relationships myself?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's clean up your types a little. GraphQL types don't need to match 1:1 with a relational structure, you have more flexibility. However it's usual practice not to include fields from other types directly in a type but just include the other type as a field (a sort of normal form if you will)

```
type ASX {
   id : ID!
   rank : Int
   price : Float
   lastDay : Float
   pastWeek : Float
   pastMonth : Float
   pastYear : Float
   mktCap : Float
   company : Company!
}

type Company {
   id : ID!
   name : String!
   code : String!
   address : String
   sector : String!
   asx : ASX
}
```

Certain GraphQL-centric frameworks (Hasura, AWS Amplify) will resolve foreign table relationships automatically based on a decorated schema definition but vanilla GraphQL *does not know* how to lookup the related company from the ASX type or how to lookup the related ASX from the company. That's a job for your resolvers.

In your case you will need to write a resolver for the `company` field under the ASX type and a resolver for the `asx` field under the `Company` type. These should just be simple SQL queries that return a single record.

For example your `company` resolver could be:

```
company: ({ companyId }) => database('company').where({ id: companyId }).first()
```

(using knexJS as your ORM)

You may find [my post about GraphQL for SQL developers](https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/graphql-for-sql-developers-part-1) helpful. It includes many code examples.

Comment: It was very kind of you to offer this detailed guidance. Much appreciated. Is it just me, or are the Apollo docs not very good? Or examples are too simple? I couldn't find this concept of building the additional resolvers, but I do jump around a lot when trying to find answers, so may have completely missed it.

Anyheew I will certainly take a look at your content and continue my journey. Thank you!

Comment: Personally I find the Apollo docs to be excellent but that's an opinion. I do agree that their examples tend to be pretty basic which is why write posts with more complex examples.